# Meaning of a notation

Tags: notation

What is the meaning of the notation [image: natation]. I cannot search for such questions on google.

Comment: It can be used to denote a map from $I$ to $\mathbb{R}$, map and function are used interchangeably in many cases. Usually we call $\mathbb{R}$ the co-domain and $I$ the domain, the word "image" is reserved for the elements in the co-domain that are mapped to by the function given over the domain.i.e $f[I] \subset \mathbb{R}$ but not always $f[I] = \mathbb{R}$

Comment: search by image ?

Answer (score 3):

It means that $f$ is a function from the set $I$ to the reals $\mathbb{R}$. Usually by $I$, one denotes an interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

$f \colon I \to \mathbb R$ means that $f$ is a *function* with *domain* $I$ and *range* $\mathbb R$. So, for every $i \in I$ there is a unique $x \in \mathbb R$ (where $\mathbb R$ is the set of all real numbers) such that $(i,x) \in f$ (we also write $f(i) = x$ for this).